# su - Automatically unlock ssh key

Tags: ssh, su, ssh-agent

On Linux there exists a tool - I believe it is ssh-agent - that can automatically unlock one's ssh key, so that when using git to fetch from a remote repository it will automatically use ones unlocked private key and one does not need to enter a password.

Now I am using `su` to switch to another user and when I do a `git pull` from within that `su` session, it asks me for my private key's password every time. I would like to know if there is a way that I can automatically unlock the private key while I have changed to another user with the `su` command.

So change to the user I usually use `su otheruser` and enter that users password.

**Update:**
I finally got it to work. Here is some more information, assume **alice** is the user that I used to login to my graphical session, and **bob** is the user that I `su` into. The `-m` option for su is not needed.

```
alice@earth $ps aux|grep ssh-agent
# added backlash to emphasize line break
alice  29878  0.0  0.0  10616   316 ?        Ss   15:49   0:00 \
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session \
    /usr/bin/im-launch \
    /usr/local/bin/my-session

alice@earth $echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-nFneWW1biI9Q/agent.29796

alice@earth $echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
29878
```

Now I su into bob

```
alice@earth $su bob
Password:

bob@earth $echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
29878

bob@earth $echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-nFneWW1biI9Q/agent.29796

bob@earth $eval $(ssh-agent)
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-unCratTnFl4M/agent.6144; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=6145; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 6145;


bob@earth $echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
6145

bob@earth $echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-unCratTnFl4M/agent.6144
```

Finally I call `ssh-add`:

```
bob@earth $ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

After that, when I run `git pull` I do not need to enter the password anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Some theory

`ssh-agent` is accessed through socket which is stored in environment variable called `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. This is probably gone if you use `su` (for security reasons). You can prevent this behaviour using `-m` switch as manual pages for `su(1)` proposes:

```
-m, -p, --preserve-environment
    Preserve the current environment, except for:
```

But (also for security reasons), this socket is accessible only for the user who created it:

```
$ ll $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
srwxrwxr-x 1 jakuje jakuje 0 Sep  2 21:23 /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

If you have some secure group you want to share this socket with, you can adjust ACL for this socket, but I don't recommend you to make it world-writeable!

## To the question

After `su` you will change the user and you will no longer have access to original socket. You will need to run new `ssh-agent` and add the keys to it (and unlock them manually):

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add path/to/your_key
```

The other possibility is to use `gnome-keyring-daemon`, which does basically the same thing, but can hide this behind some master password (usually login password). But the question doesn't state the used tool so I can only guess what is intention.

Comment: If I understand it correctly when I am logged in with user *alice* then ssh-agent also runs in the context of user *alice* and only knows about alice's private keys. Now when I switch to *bob* with `su bob`, accessing alice's instance of ssh-agent will not help me, will it? Instead is it possible to start a new instance of ssh-agent for the user *bob* so that while inside the su environment for bob I can access *bob's* private keys for his ssh sessions?

Comment: @lanoxx Yes. As you write.

Comment: but if I type `su bob` followed by `ssh-agent` it seems to have no effect, it prints some information like SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AUTH_PID but when I use ssh I still need to enter my password.

Comment: you need to start ssh-agent as `eval $(ssh-agent)` so the environment variables will store into local shell and you will have the connection.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me either. Could you update your answer and give a more comprehensive example?

Comment: @lanoxx edited answer with the related stuff. If you would provide more information I wouldn't have to guess. What does your `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable look like?

Comment: `ssh-add` did the trick. Thanks alot for you patience and detailed explanations. I also updated my question to show what I did in more detail. But with some more details of the state of the variables.